# overflow with position absolute

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with another `div` inside. The second `div` have `width`,`height` and `background-color: green`. This one has absolute position and so its container isn't shown.

```
<div id="root">

<div id="r1">

    <div id="r2">

    </div>
</div>
Mas
</div>
```

CSS  file

```
#root{
width:300px;
background-color: red;
}

#r1{

position: relative;
width: 100px;
background: yellow;

}

#r2{
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
left: 0;
background-color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sev2E/1/

I want to know if it's possible that its container is shown and wrap the div with absolute position.

I want to see something like this but without using relative position and without adding height to its container.

http://jsfiddle.net/sev2E/2/

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the related codes in your question too.

Comment: When you declare a div as absolute then it is not included inside the parent tag. So wrapping cannot be done as you need.

Comment: ` without using relative position and without adding height` ? any reason ?

Comment: @zey yes, i want to find a similar way in CSS to "WRAP_CONTENT" attribute in Android layouts... thanks for all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add some height to your r1 css

```
#r1{

    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    height:60px;
```

or adding a padding-bottom:"height of your div" which is same

```
#r1{

    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    padding-bottom:55px

}
```

Comment: I want to know if i can do this without adding height to its container...i update my question and i say this. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: i think by giving your object position absolute ,you make your div kind of " empty " ,that's why it gets height 0

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer is no.**

Once you absolutely position an element, it is taken out of the document flow and it will no longer be factored into computing the height or width of its containing block.

The text formatting model used by the Android API (written in Java) is different from that implemented by modern browsers that are CSS compliant.

To get similar visual effects between a CSS based web page and an Android interface layout, you need to code each implementation according to the rules and constraints of each language being used.

The answer by Pumpkinpro is essentially the way to get the "wrap_content" effect in CSS.

Comment: Thanks! Well...i'll have to change my java code to use CSS model instead of android model T_T